# Android FileObserver example in Xamarin/C#?

Tags: c#, android, file, xamarin, observers

I need guidance in creating a file observer in Xamarin c# (Android)

Some sort of workable example would be wonderful !

I've tried to convert the java ones over to C# but due to my lack on experience in the C# environment, it's throwing too many errors when being compiled .. and getting the write reference code within C# vs java is proving irritating ..

So PLEASE !, may someone out there point me to some sort of workable

This is a java example of a file observer
https://gist.github.com/shirou/659180

Comment: you mean File Explorer?

Comment: no, a Fileobserver .. to see when a file gets accessed or modified

Comment: I added a java example

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  That example appears to be inheriting from the Android FileObserver and not doing much else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a class that inherits from [`Android.OS.FileObserver`](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.FileObserver/), you only need to implement the [`OnEvent()`](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.OS.FileObserver.OnEvent/p/Android.OS.FileObserverEvents/System.String/) and one(+) Constructors. Its a really simple pattern after you see it once... ;-)

**Notes:**

- Watch on a **path**, if you need to filter by file, do it in the OnEvent
- Do not let your FileObserver object get GC'd or your OnEvents will magically stop :-/
- Remember to call StartWatching() in order to receive OnEvent calls

**FileObserver Class:**

```
using System;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;

namespace MyFileObserver
{
    public class MyPathObserver : Android.OS.FileObserver
    {
        static FileObserverEvents _Events = (FileObserverEvents.AllEvents);
        const string tag = "StackoverFlow";

        public MyPathObserver (String rootPath) : base(rootPath, _Events)
        {
            Log.Info(tag, String.Format("Watching : {0}", rootPath)); 
        }

        public MyPathObserver (String rootPath, FileObserverEvents events) : base(rootPath, events)
        {
            Log.Info(tag, String.Format("Watching : {0} : {1}", rootPath, events)); 
        }

        public override void OnEvent(FileObserverEvents e, String path)
        {
            Log.Info(tag, String.Format("{0}:{1}",path, e)); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
var pathToWatch = System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
// Do not let myFileObserver get GC'd, stash it's ref in an activty, or ...
myFileObserver = new MyPathObserver (pathToWatch);
myFileObserver.StartWatching (); // and StopWatching () when you are done...
var document = Path.Combine(pathToWatch, "StackOverFlow.txt");
button.Click += delegate {
    if (File.Exists (document)) {
        button.Text = "Delete File";
        File.Delete (document);
    } else {
        button.Text = "Create File";
        File.WriteAllText (document, "Foobar");
    }
};
```

**adb logcat Output (when clicking on the test button):**

```
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:Create
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:Open
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:Modify
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:CloseWrite
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:Delete
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:Create
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:Open
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:Modify
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:CloseWrite
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:Delete
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:Create
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:Open
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:Modify
I/StackoverFlow( 3596): StackOverFlow.txt:CloseWrite
```

Comment: 1 question - what is "Do not let your FileObserver object get GC'd "

Comment: Don't let it get "Garbage Collected", define it as a variable at the class level (like in an activity) as if you assign it to a local method variable it will go out of scope and it will be available to be GC'd since it has no references anywhere....

Comment: Thanks Robert, you are a kind person to help me .. unlike those that are putting this question on hold ..