# FileObserver class always has null value for path in OnEvent(FileObserverEvents e, String path)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

This question is extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703113/android-fileobserver-example-in-xamarin-c) question. Posting another question because that is closed.

I am implementing the FileObserver Class as mentioned by [@SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover) but when the event (**OnEvent**) is fired then the value of path is null and the value of e is 1073741856.

This is how I am initializing the FileObserver as suggested by [@SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover)

```
[Activity(Label = "Main Menu")]
public class MainView : MvxActivity
{
    public MusicFolderObserver MusicFolderObserver;

    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        File musicFolder = new File(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryMusic), "/MyFolder");
        MusicFolderObserver = new MusicFolderObserver (musicFolder.AbsolutePath);
        MusicFolderObserver.StartWatching();
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.View_Main);
    }
}
```

and following is the File observer Class

```
public class MusicFolderObserver : FileObserver
{

    static FileObserverEvents _Events = (FileObserverEvents.AllEvents);
    const string tag = "StackoverFlow";

    public MusicFolderObserver (String rootPath) : base(rootPath, _Events)
    {
        Log.Info(tag, String.Format("Watching : {0}", rootPath));
    }

    public MusicFolderObserver (String rootPath, FileObserverEvents events) : base(rootPath, events)
    {
        Log.Info(tag, String.Format("Watching : {0} : {1}", rootPath, events));
    }

    public override void OnEvent(FileObserverEvents e, String path)
    {
        Log.Info(tag, String.Format("{0}:{1}", path, e));
    }
}
```

Please let me know how can I make this observer active for the entire duration the app is running. I am trying to make an app which is active 24/7 and triggers if there is any change in the observed Music folder

Answer (score 0):

A `FileObserverEvents` of `1073741856` **contains** a `FileObserverEvents.Open`flag:

```
if (e.HasFlag(FileObserverEvents.Open))
{
    Log.Debug(tag, $"File Opened : {path}");
}
```

When Android (Linux) manipulates a file in a directory you might get a series of events as it alters the contents of the directory, a lot of these actions (`FileObserverEvents`) will have no path attached to them and those can be ignored in your case (if you want details of all the event flags when you get a null path, consult a Linux file system reference).

#### `OnEvent` override example:

```
public override void OnEvent(FileObserverEvents e, String path)
{
    if (path == null) return;
    Log.Debug(tag, $"{path} : {e}");
}
```

#### `Touch` a new file:

```
adb shell touch /sdcard/Music/MyFolder/BohemianRhapsody100.mp3
```

Results in:

```
SO      : BohemianRhapsody100.mp3 : Create
SO      : BohemianRhapsody100.mp3 : Open
SO      : BohemianRhapsody100.mp3 : CloseNowrite
```

#### Moving a file:

```
adb shell mv /sdcard/Music/MyFolder/BohemianRhapsody100.mp3 /sdcard/Music/MyFolder/BohemianRhapsody101.mp3
```

Results in:

```
SO      : BohemianRhapsody100.mp3 : MovedFrom
SO      : BohemianRhapsody101.mp3 : MovedTo
```

#### Deleting a file:

```
adb shell rm /sdcard/Music/MyFolder/BohemianRhapsody101.mp3
```

Results in:

```
SO      : BohemianRhapsody101.mp3 : Delete
```

etc....